# HE3D Prusa Z-Axis Motor Error

Tags: prusa-i3

I have an HE3D Prusa XI3 that I have assembled but the z axis motors aren't functioning properly, they will whine instead of turn. They will turn if I use Z babystepping or position changes but will not when doing a fast position changes or in normal use

Answer (score 2):

You are probably driving the motors with insufficient current. Try increasing the motor current, by adjusting the potentiometer on the respective stepper driver. Turn it clockwise until your motors stop skipping steps.

Comment: I've been playing with that... The Z-axis motors are running in parallel in this model, I think the A4988 isn't strong enough to torque two Nema 17's in parallel, but all this is rather foreign to me.

Comment: I realize that the motors are wired in series, not parallel. Sorry for the confusion.